# android TextView setHint occurs indexOutOfBounds error

Tags: android

When I use TextView I found a problem as [Android EditText Width because Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290495/android-edittext-width-because-hint) described. so I use the solution, and then the error happened with very low probability, the stack detail is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1331)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:685)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:94)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:153)
    at android.widget.Editor$VigourInsertionHandleView.updateSelectPosition(Editor.java:7731)
    at android.widget.Editor$VigourInsertionHandleView.endFollowHandle(Editor.java:7643)
    at android.widget.Editor$VigourInsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:7558)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:15275)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3148)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.cancelAndClearTouchTargets(ViewGroup.java:2981)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3984)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5754)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:9224)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:9200)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:516)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:457)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.dismissImmediate(PopupWindow.java:2444)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.dismiss(PopupWindow.java:2378)
    at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.dismiss(Editor.java:5413)
    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.dismiss(Editor.java:6278)
    at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.hide(Editor.java:5423)
    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.hide(Editor.java:7020)
    at android.widget.Editor.hideInsertionPointCursorController(Editor.java:1102)
    at android.widget.Editor.prepareCursorControllers(Editor.java:1084)
    at android.widget.TextView.nullLayouts(TextView.java:9513)
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:10354)
    at android.widget.TextView.setHintInternal(TextView.java:6917)
    at android.widget.TextView.setHint(TextView.java:6906)
```

Is it a system bug, and how to resolve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`, typically occurs when you're trying to set a span on a SpannableStringBuilder that specifies a range outside the valid bounds of the text. This can happen when you're manipulating the text in a way that results in an incorrect range being specified for a span. In your case, it seems to be related to setting a hint on a TextView.

**XML:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your hint text here" />
```

The `android:hint` attribute directly sets the hint text for the **TextView** without the need for additional code.

**JAVA:**

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setHint("Your hint text here");
```

This should set the hint for the TextView without causing an **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Comment: After a period of online verification, I am convinced that this is a system bug on some vivo models.Anyway thanks for your answer